# Elasticsearch result count shows less than what it should be

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure why when I search for the documents from an index I'm only getting 10 when it tells me I have more. From the image below you can see that it says there are `45 hits` but when I count the number of `hits` it's far less than that.[image]

The command I used to grab the documents is:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/contextual_original/_search/?pretty
```

I know the count of 45 is correct but I'm not sure why only 10 of them are showing up. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, elasticsearch limits the number of results that match your search to 10.

You must set the [`size`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#:%7E:text=The%20size%20parameter%20is%20the,define%20a%20page%20of%20results.&text=Avoid%20using%20from%20and%20size,requests%20usually%20span%20multiple%20shards.) parameter if you want to obtain more hits. The "size" parameter is used to provide the maximum number of results for a search that you want to return.

Modify your command as shown below (for suppose you want to retrieve 20 documents)

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/contextual_original/_search/?size=20&pretty
```